# redirect to cshtml page from angularjs controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

// AngularJs controller method

```
  $scope.onLogOutClick = function () // called when i clicked on logout button
         {  

                       //i want here to redirect to login.cshtml file.
                   $http({ method: 'GET', url: "/Home/Login"}); 
                      // this line of code is not working.

         }
```

//controller method return logic.cshtml view.

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login(string theme, string feature)
    {
         return View("login");  // i want to render this view in angularJs
    }
```

When i clicked on logout button than onLogOutClick() method is called. i want to redirect back login.cshtml page when i clicked on logout button.

Comment: are you using mvc or angularjs for routing??

Comment: i want routing from angularjs to mvc(.cshtml) file. Actually our application load first page through mvc later sub-sequence page is created on angularJs. When i clicked logout then i want to redirect to first page(which is on MVC(.cshtml page)) .

Comment: in mvc, you route to controller/action and not to cshtml...

Comment: This questions shows a real lack of understanding of MVC and JavaScript, and general knowledge of how web works. I suggest you go back to basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AndularJs we can develop Single page application(SPA). In SPA has only one CSHTML file(Main Page) and we change views(render html) using ng-view and $roughtConfig directive. So there is no case to arise to switch cshtml page.

Comment: This is not correct, it is possible to develop an MVC as a collection of independent single page applications per action and offload authentication and even template rendering to the MVC. To be fair there are any number of combinations of architecture depending on the scenario and requirements. This answer just looks like a cheap shot at answering a poorly thought out question

Answer (score 0):

1) Add Blank Logout.cshtml page.
2) Add routing for Logout page

```
.when('/Logout', { templateUrl: '/Login/LogoutUser', controller: 'LogoutController' })
```

3) Add following controller to redirect user to login page

```
angular.module('Application').controller("LogoutController", ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', function LogoutController($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    var requestLogout = $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/api/LoginUser/LogoutUser"
    });
    requestLogout.success((function myNewfunction() {
        window.location.href = "/Login?session=false";
    }));
}]);
```